# Installed numpy and scipy on ubuntu, but python won't see them

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ubuntu-12.04

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I've installed the numpy and scipy packages with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

When I run this command now, it says that the latest versions are already installed.

However, when I go into python in the command prompt and ask it to "import numpy", it says no such module is installed. It's the same for scipy and matplotlib. What's going on?

Comment: Have you installed a version of python by some means other than apt-get? In a terminal what does `which python` print?

Comment: Looks like python2 packages and python3 interpreter. Try `import numpy` in both python2 and python3.

Comment: I've tried it in both... it doesn't seem to work. which python returns /usr/local/bin/python. I remember trying to install python a different way - don't recall how - back when I first got ubuntu setup. Then I learned that python was pre-installed on ubuntu. Maybe I have two python2.7's installed because of that?

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/python2 -c 'import numpy; print numpy.__version__'`  to test if the Ubuntu-provided python can see numpy.  It seems like your /usr/local/.. version is getting in the way.

Comment: It can see it from there! So when running python, I need to type in the full address /usr/bin/python2? Is there a way I can change the "default" python?